# Unix time stamp to date and hour in google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, timestamp, unix-timestamp, seconds

I am working in Google Sheets. How can I convert a timestamp in seconds (as type of `1634978274`) to the format of `2021-10-23 08:23`, e.g. Date, hours; Minutes and how can I store this result in a new column? The original timestamp as such should not be changed, though.

Unfortunately, I am not sure by which number to divide the timestamp as such to receive the correct date.

I strive to filter for the dates and hours, which is why I need to transform the timestamp in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your unix / epoch time is in seconds use:

```
=TEXT(A2/86400+DATE(1970, 1, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

without seconds:

```
=TEXT(A2/86400+DATE(1970, 1, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
```

[image]

---

if your unix / epoch time is in milliseconds use:

```
=TEXT(A2/86400000+DATE(1970, 1, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000")
```

[image]

---

for array use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="",,TEXT(A1:A/86400+DATE(1970, 1, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot; this works!

Comment: I have now a timestamp of the form 1643733039331616475 and it doesn't work anymore.. could you help me out @player0?

Comment: @Baobab is this it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLd2N.png

Answer (score 3):

Unix time counts the number of elapsed seconds from an origin of January 1, 1970. So to convert to Sheets time:

`=DATE(1970,1,1) + 1634978274/(60*60*24)`

... where `60*60*24` = "60 seconds per minute x 60 minutes per hour x 24 hours per day."

Then you can format the formula cell (or range) with the Date/Time format of your choice.

If your Unix time will be entered into a cell, of course you can substitute `1634978274` in the formula with that cell reference, e.g.:

`=DATE(1970,1,1) + A1/(24*60*60)`

Comment: Thank you, this alternative works as well.